# How to disable command for DataGridColumn's header?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hey I'm using a DataGrid in my WPF MVVM app like this

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="SearchGrid"
              ...>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Type">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   ...
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="6*"
                                Binding="{Binding Reference}"
                                Header="Reference" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="9*"
                                Binding="{Binding Description}"
                                Header="Description" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=SelectElementCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=SearchGrid}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

When I double click a row in my grid the 'SelectElementCommand' is executed and when I click on a header the rows are getting sorted. Everything is OK so far. But when I double click a header the command is executed aswell. How to stop that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you Check preview event of mouse double click event instead of MouseDoubleClick event?

Comment: I can try, I dont see a problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can do it by passing  Mouse DoubleClick EventArgs To the Command:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=SelectElementCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and the corresponded SelectElementCommand looks like so :

```
 private RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> _selectElementCommand;
    public RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs> SelectElementCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectElementCommand
                ?? (_selectElementCommand= new RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(
                    (s) =>
                    {
                        var dep = s.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
                        //go up the treeView until you find the ColumnHeader if existed 
                        while (dep != null && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
                        {
                            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
                        }

                        if (!(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
                            //you handler logic 

                    }));
        }
    }
```

I don't see why you are passing the SelectedItem as a CommandParametre since you could simply define it as a property in your ViewModel:

```
 private YourRowType  _selectedItem ;
    public YourRowType SelectedItem 
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I made some minor changes to your solution. But basically you are right. I bound the SelectedItem of the DataGrid to a property in my vm and passed the mousebuttoneventargs for the command. Thanks alot

Comment: Hi can u share the code . i was unable to find the datagrid header by passing eventargs